# Dragging a shape in Java

Tags: java, swing, drag, shapes, mouselistener

I am working on some code to drag a shape (currently a square) around a container (JPanel).  I have been able to draw a blue square and my mouse listener is working because I can drag the square.  BUT it is still not doing what I want it to do, for the following reasons:

1. I can only drag the shape diagonally.  In other words, no matter where I move my mouse, the shape only moves in a diagonal up or down the screen.
2. I can only drag the shape once.  In other words, if I click inside the shape, drag it to a new position, and then release the mouse, that's it - I cannot move it any more without restarting the program.

Here are the relevant (I hope!) sections of my code:

1. Declaration of DragPanel class (basically an extension of a JPanel):

   ```
   public class DragPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
   {
   Graphics2D g2;
   Rectangle2D square;
   Color colour;

   double x1, y1, x2, y2, size;
   double offsetX, offsetY;

   boolean dragging = false;
   ```
2. Constructor method:

   ```
   public DragPanel()
   {

   x1 = 10.0;
   y1 = 10.0;
   size = 40.0;
   x2 = x1 + size;
   y2 = y1 + size;

   square = new Rectangle2D.Double(x1, y1, size, size);
   colour = Color.BLUE;

   setFocusable(true);
   addMouseListener(this);
   addMouseMotionListener(this);
   this.requestFocus();

   }
   ```
3. PaintComponent Method, and MouseDragged, MousePressed, MouseReleased methods:

   ```
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
   {

   super.paintComponent(g);
   g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
   g2.draw(square);
   g2.setColor(colour);
   g2.draw(square);

   }

   @Override
   public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent ev) 
   {
       if (dragging)
       {
       double mx = ev.getX();
       double my = ev.getY();

       x1 = mx - offsetX;
       y1 = mx - offsetY;
       square = new Rectangle2D.Double(x1, y1, size, size);
       repaint();  
       }

   }

   @Override
   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent ev) 
   {
   double mx = ev.getX();
   double my = ev.getY();

   if (mx > x1 && mx < x2 && my > y1 && my < y2)
   {
       dragging = true;
       offsetX  = mx - x1;
       offsetY = my - y1;
   }

   }

   @Override
   public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) 
   {
   dragging = false;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

in mouseDragged()

```
x1 = mx - offsetX;
y1 = mx - offsetY;
```

should be

```
x1 = mx - offsetX;
y1 = my - offsetY;
x2 = x1 + size;
y2 = y1 + size;
```

You need to update all the bounds of the square each time its moved. Instead of explicitly storing them in instance variables, I you use the built in rectangle 2D methods like getMinX() and getMaxX()

Comment: Ooops!  I feel like an idiot now! ;-)

(Though I know that was not your intention!)

Comment: Well that worked, but I still can't drag more than once.  I think it has something to do with the "dragging = false" in the mouseReleased() method, because when I remove this, it works, but then I have no way of stopping the square moving if the mouse drag is outside the square.

Comment: @Sam found the problem with dragging multiple times

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it to work!  I had to add:

```
        x2 = x1 + size;
        y2 = y1 + size;
```

To my mouseDragged() method as follows:

```
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent ev) 
{
    if (dragging)
    {
        double mx = ev.getX();
        double my = ev.getY();

        x1 = mx - offsetX;
        y1 = my - offsetY;
        x2 = x1 + size;
        y2 = y1 + size;
        square = new Rectangle2D.Double(x1, y1, size, size);
        repaint();  
    }


}
```